# Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I'm adding an object to a list within an ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the following code but one of the properties of the object is giving me difficulties.

```
ls.Add(new UserRoleModel { UserRoleId = 1, UserName = "Paul", InsertDate = new DateTime(05, 24, 2012),InsertProgram="sqlplus",InsertUser="sp22",Role="Implementation Co-corindator"});
```

This builds but when I go to the relevant page i get an Exception with the following type:

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
```

I've tried removing the 0 in the month but I get the same exception.

Comment: Perhaps this has something to do with the "Culture" you are using?  Are you using a culture that has a different order for each of the elements (year, month, day) instead of (month, day, year) ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx  This link shows some examples of how you'd change this.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `DateTime` [constructor you are calling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx) accepts parameters in the order year, month, day.

You are providing them in the order month, day, year -- which ends up trying to assign meaningless values. The documentation is pretty clear on what the allowed values are and what happens if you pass 2012 for the "day" value.

Comment: Also, months and days are 1-indexed, so to get the first month and day of the year, use `new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)` (I don't know if there is another function for this).

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into this and my issue was I was creating a date in February. I tried to do the following...

```
new Date(2013, 2, 30)
```

Since there is not a February 30th, the date failed to create.  When I changed to

```
new Date(2013, 2, 28)
```

it worked fine.

Comment: new Date(2013, 2, 28) will fail if the current year in question is a leap year (because of 29 days in February, for example today is 02-29-2016)

Comment: @kishoreperla 28 will always work, leap year or not.  The first number, 30, that I had did not.  I believe I had switched from Jan to Feb.

Answer (score 2):

if the `InsertDate` meant to be the date / time of creation you can just use the following

```
DateTime InsertDate  = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an Invalid datetime, like for month you may be passing 13,14 days more than 31

or something like that which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

i was having the same issue because i was trying to create a DateTime object with date set to 31 of April even though April only has 30 days.
Anyone having the same issue, make sure you are not making this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you have to change the InsertDate into

```
InsertDate = new DateTime(Year,Month,Date);
```

It will solve your problem.

I was facing the same type of issue, where I was using a DateTimePicker in Winform Application. Where user can only pick only month and year and my code and UI was look like [image]

### Code

```
            this.dtpMonth.CustomFormat = "MMMM yyyy";
            this.dtpMonth.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0)));
            this.dtpMonth.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            this.dtpMonth.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(88, 24);
            this.dtpMonth.Name = "dtpMonth";
            this.dtpMonth.ShowUpDown = true;
            this.dtpMonth.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(136, 22);
            this.dtpMonth.TabIndex = 1;
```

And I was initializing the by `this.dtpMonth=DateTime.Today;` and this line cost me and error of current discussion.

Afterward, I have found that my date(DateTime.Today) was 31 July. So, when user want change the month to August it throws exception because August doesn't have date 31. Finally, I change my code into

```
 dtpMonth.Value =new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month,1);
```

And worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

if you got this error because you're trying to insert 29 days in a year that's not a leap year, then you can check the maximum allowed days first of that year as such:

```
if(DateTime.DaysInMonth(2024,2) == 29)
   dt = new DateTime(2024, 2, 29);
```

Answer (score 0):

The same exception I solved as:

```cs
DateTimePicker1.Value = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) + 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who has this issue, make sure that date, which you try to create exists. For example, I had this problem, because was trying to create 29 feb at not leap year