# Year, Month, and Day parameters desribe an un-representable DateTime

Tags: android, datetime, datepicker, xamarin, xamarin.android

I just stumbled upon an exception: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime`. When I select the date 31st of May, 2015 in a DatePicker in my app, I got the exception. After googling it, I found [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246563/year-month-and-day-parameters-describe-an-un-representable-datetime-exception), where [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14984884/2111834) seems to describe the exception I met. The answer regards February, with leap years in mind though. Why would it crash on 4-31-2015, but not any other date I've tried? It occurred on Android 4.4.4 as well as 5.0.2. Please help me!

Comment: @samgak I appreciate you pointing this out, but my question regards May, not Februari.

Comment: 4-31 is April, not May

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DatePicker](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3AAndroid.Widget.DatePicker.Init(System.Int32%2CSystem.Int32%2CSystem.Int32%2CAndroid.Widget.DatePicker.IOnDateChangedListener)) uses 0-based months:

> monthOfYear
>   The initial month starting from zero.

whereas [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx) is numbers the months from one:

> month
>   The month (1 through 12).

So when setting a DateTime from a DatePicker you need to add 1. April, June, September and November have [only 30 days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_days_hath_September), so without this conversion May (0-based 4) 31st will end up as April 31st which is an invalid date.

Comment: The DatePicker returns the month as 1 less than the gregorian calendar would. So, January would be 0, whereas May would be 4. In order to avoid this exception, should I add +1 to the month when setting the DateTime?

Comment: Yes that's correct, DateTime is 1-based, so you have to add one.